# I call same service multiple times (AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, afnetworking

Is there any way to operate only last call when i call same service multiple times, in a such way that other async calls (to different services) must not be affected? When i try with `[self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]`, it cancels all calls.

Thanks in advance.

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can store the reference to AFHTTPRequestOperation object corresponding to the service and you can cancel only that operation, while calling same service again. Or if you do not want to store the reference to AFHTTPRequestOperation, then iterate through all operations in operation queue and cancel the operation based on the request(NSURLRequest*) property.

Comment: Thanks my solution for (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation in self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue.operations) {
        NSURL *url = operation.request.URL ;
        NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
        if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"TaskList"].location != NSNotFound) {
            [operation cancel];
        }
    }

Comment: OK,nice. This is same as the second one that is suggested in the answer.